# launchd: Confusion on semantics of bootstrap and bootout etc. after reading manual pages

Tags: launchd, plist, services, launch-services

I've read the following manual pages on launchd: `launchctl`, `launchd`, and `launchd.plist`.

However, nothing is really said in these manual pages regarding what the `launchctl boostrap` and `launchctl bootout` (sub)commands actually do (see below). Is it to be inferred from their names?

Futhermore, I cannot find information in the man pages, regarding what user/group the service (agent/daemon) runs as. However, `launchd.plist` mentions `UserName`/`GroupName` for controlling the user/group for the system domain. So, what user are per-user services in `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `~/Library/LaunchAgents` run as?

Finally, I would expect I need to `bootstrap`/`load` my `daemon`'s .plist, but after putting the .plist in `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, it was automatically loaded (run) at system boot. Indeed, `RunAtLoad=true`, but what's the purpose of `bootstrap`, if services run anyway?

`man launchctl`:

```
 bootstrap | bootout domain-target [service-path service-path2 ...] | service-target
          Bootstraps or removes domains and services. When service arguments are present, bootstraps and correspondingly removes their definitions into the domain.  Services may be specified as a series of
          paths or a service identifier.  Paths may point to XPC service bundles, launchd.plist(5) s, or a directories containing a collection of either. If there were one or more errors while bootstrapping or
          removing a collection of services, the problematic paths will be printed with the errors that occurred.

          If no paths or service target are specified, these commands can either bootstrap or remove a domain specified as a domain target. Some domains will implicitly bootstrap pre-defined paths as part of
          their creation.
```

Answer (score 26):

LaunchAgents are basically  the same as LaunchDaemons, except that:

- **LaunchAgents** runs only after the user Logs in, process runs on the Logged in UID (User ID) with the logged user privileges. Process can interact with the logged user via GUI.
- **LaunchDaemons** runs on boot time, before the GUI is up, during the progress bar on the boot screen. It run as root, there is no need to have any logged user, run in pure background (like windows system services, or Linux rc.d daemons), it cannot interact with any user on the GUI. [This is basically for system services, but you can have your own service] (personally I have a launchDaemon that downloads and update my /etc/hosts file blocking some malicious URLs, it is a bash script I created as a service)

`/Library/LaunchAgents/` - (For all users) [load after **any user** logs in]

`~/Library/LaunchAgents/` - (for a SPECIFIC user) [load after he/she logs in]

--
To load means 'run the service', you load it on memory. But it may not run exactly on load time, if your internal plist setting sets for example a timer to run, after X hours.

Eg: create my custom daemon at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/local.updateHosts.plist`

I will load it:

```sh
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.updateHosts.plist
```

'Load' must point to the `path/to/file.plist`

**you may have to kickstart it after loading, this way it will be executed, finish, and wait for the next execution time (if it is a timed service like mine)*

Since it is on LaunchDaemon, it is a system service.

**[a brief pause here about launchctl]**

Because to continue we need to understand the MacOS process execution architecture:

---

## MacOS Bootstraps domains, sessions and namespaces

Additionally to BSD process contexts [ UID ], MacOS has the Mach bootstrap process contexts, called namespaces.

A namespace is like a 'place' or grouping, where various process runs.

Bootstrap namespaces are arranged hierarchically. There is a **System** global namespace, below it we have a **per-user** namespace (non GUI), and below it we have a **per-session** GUI namespace [created by the WindowServer when the user logs in via GUI] .

Hierarchically, each lower level can access all their upper-levels namespace services (their parents services processes)

```
System_Namespace
     Per-User_Namespace
         Per-Session_Namespace(GUI WindowServer)
```

Technically the GUI per-session namespace is
called 'Aqua' Session by Apple's API docs.

The hierarchy above shows the System Domain, the User Domain and the Session Domain (which belongs to the user, each user has its own)

An expanded view with 2 logged users is below:

```
----
System_Namespace [System]
   |
   ------ PerUSER_Namespace [Background] [user 501]
   |      |
   |      ----- PerSESSION_Namespace [Aqua] (MacOS GUI WindowServer) [user 501]
   |
   |
   ------ PerUSER_Namespace [Background] [user 502]
          |
          ----- PerSESSION_Namespace [Aqua] (MacOS GUI WindowServer) [user 502]
```

This is exactly the root of the security architecture of the MacOS, it is called the Mach Layer, that works in conjunction with the BSD Layer (which takes care about user file permissions and other linux/bsd/unix permissions).

MacOS has 2 distinct security mechanisms integrated and working together: the **Unix** + the **Mach** security mechanisms.

---

Continuing about `launchctl``, when you are about to create a daemon/service you have to choose where it will run, which domain, and which context.

First, lets print the **system domain** services, this will list all launchdaemons, loaded or not, enabled and disabled one.

`sudo launchctl print system/`

Now, lets print the current user's domain services:

`sudo launchctl print "user/$(id -u)"`

(`id -u` will get the current User's ID. It's usually `501` for single-user machines. You can look up any other user by their username with `id some_username`. Since Catalina, you can use usernames directly: `sudo launchctl print user/some_username`)

You can also query a PID, and check under which domain and namespace it is running:

`sudo launchctl print pid/784` (considering 784 is the PID of Finder for example)

```sh
$ sudo launchctl print pid/758
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Finder.758 = {
    type = process
    handle = 758
    active count = 91
    on-demand count = 1
    service count = 90
    active service count = 2
    activity ratio = 0.02
    originator = /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
    creator = Finder.758
    creator euid = 503
    uniqueid = 758
    external activation count = 0
    security context = {
        uid = 503
        asid = 100008
    }

    bringup time = 20 ms
    death port = 0x52a63

    in-progress bootstraps = 0
    pended requests = 0
    pending requests = {
    }
    subdomains = {
    }
    pending attachments = {
    }

    task-special ports = {
             0x3fc73 4       bootstrap  com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.503.100008.Aqua
             0x15f03 9          access  com.apple.taskgated
    }
}
```

Under Security Context:

- uid = 503 -> process is running for user id 503
- asid = 100008 -> process is running on GUI session 100008

---

`com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Finder.758`
`com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.503.100008.Aqua``

Means:

- Finder, which has PID `758`
- was created by launchd,
- under the **user domain**,
- for user `503`,
- which is running a graphical interface with session ID `100008`.

---

Now you can choose and control domain, namespaces and user for your daemon.

**bootout** means stop a service that is running, for ex:

```sh
sudo launchctl bootout system/com.apple.netbiosd
```

This stops the NetBIOS daemon.

__
Lets go back to that service we created with this command:

```sh
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.updateHosts.plist
```

## `load` subcommand

`load` is the only subcommand where you pass the full path of the `.plist` file, unlike all other other `launchctl` subcommands, which work **via reference** from domain hierarchy!

So to print our service, we use:

```sh
sudo launchctl print system/local.updateHosts`
```

you don't use the extension `.plist`, and the reference is system/process.name

The process name is what you define inside the plist file under key `Label``:

```xml
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.updateHosts</string>
```

## `bootstrap` subcommand

The `bootstrap` subcommand is to force load your service while choosing which domain or namespace you want to make it run, ex:

```sh
sudo launchctl bootstrap user/503 /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.updateHosts.plist

/Library/LaunchDaemons/local.updateHosts.plist: Service cannot load in requested session
```

The command above returned error because my service plist file only allow my service to run as a system service, otherwise it would have been started for user `503``.

`bootstrap` lets you start any service or XPC service bundle under other domains/namespaces. Basically you choose a **service** AND a **target** for it to run.

### Additional syntax

```sh
sudo launchctl start system/local.updateHosts
sudo launchctl stop system/local.updateHosts
sudo launchctl unload system/local.updateHosts
sudo launchctl kickstart system/local.updateHosts
```

---

If you want to go ultra-deep on this topic, I suggest this [excellent documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/contexts/contexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH212-BEHJDFCA), which is very technical and very detailed.

Comment: Thank you @Prado for an excellent answer. However, I've the following questions. Is `bootstrap`s "force load" different from loading using `load`?  Is "namespace" the as "domain"?  Why is `bootstrap` (or `load`) necessary, if all services in e.g. `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`  are loaded automatically at boot or when the user logs in? Will all services, except timed, run after load? And finally, do you also find the `man` pages poor, and where have you learned this, besides your listed reference?

Comment: Not all services under those directory are loaded. If the service is Disabled, it will be there but will not be loaded. The comamand `load` enables it to be loaded. Try using the command `disable` you will see the files are still there, but it will not be loaded on boot

Comment: Any plist in the appropriate directory will be loaded on its own at boot or login. `load` is a legacy command. It appears that `bootstrap` is preferred if you don't want to reboot (or simply log out and log back in).