# How to change a system startup daemon into a user launch agent

Tags: launchd, startup, plist

I'm using The Pritunl VPN software for one of my Mac's user accounts. The software installer creates a system LaunchDaemon found under `/Library/LaunchDaemons` called `com.pritunl.service.plist`

Unfortunately this service remains active when I log out from the user profile it's intended for, causing the VPN connection to also remain active for different user accounts.

What I would like to do is to remove this service from the /system/ and add it as a /user/username startup service. My intention is for the service to be started whenever I log in with the specific user and for it to stop whenever the user is logged out.

What I've tried to do so far is to unload the system service, remove the .plist from the system directory `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and to move it to the user directory `~/Library/LaunchAgents` after which I attempted loading and registering it for the specific user account. I've not yet succeeded in performing these steps correctly as the user account in question does not have root access.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.pritunl.service</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Pritunl.app/Contents/Resources/pritunl-service</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Umask</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

```
sudo launchctl list com.pritunl.service
{
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
    "Label" = "com.pritunl.service";
    "OnDemand" = false;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "PID" = XXXX;
    "Program" = "/Applications/Pritunl.app/Contents/Resources/pritunl-service";
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/Applications/Pritunl.app/Contents/Resources/pritunl-service";
    );
};
```

Reference material I've used: https://rakhesh.com/mac/macos-launchctl-commands/

When trying to learn more about LimitLoadToSessionType I've only managed to find this archived older documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html

Trying to find it on the current documentation page hasn't resulted in what I'm looking for. https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=LimitLoadToSessionType

I've found this excellent post detailing a lot of related subjects. [launchd: Confusion on semantics of bootstrap and bootout etc. after reading manual pages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366281/launchd-confusion-on-semantics-of-bootstrap-and-bootout-etc-after-reading-manu)

Comment: Could you show us the plist please.

Comment: @TonyWilliams I've editted the question to include the plist.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is the LimitLoadToSessionType key. All my user agents have that set to "Aqua" which I am guessing means the Finder is running with a logged in user. Fix this first.

You shouldn't need root access or admin rights to do the required steps.

If you go `launchctl print user` you will get told that is invalid and it should list all the targets you can access. If things are working one of them should be `gui/501/com.pritunl.service`so then `launchctl print gui/501/com.pritunl.service` should dump a good guide to what the Mac is thinking about the agent you are specifying. If you don't see it then try loading it again or reboot the box and have another look.