LaunchDeamon file doesn't work
I have a .plist file in the LaunchDeamons directory. It's supposed to run a .sh file (which works) which creates a backup of a directory onto an external drive every day at 00:00. I have tried putting this plist file into LaunchAgents and it still won't work.
This is the .plist file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.postgres.backup.0000</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/tristan/Documents/Server_Backup/Backup.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

I ran these commands which I got from here:
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.postgres.backup.daily.0000.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.postgres.backup.daily.0000.plist
sudo launchctl start /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.postgres.backup.daily.0000.plist

But the error persists:
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

I ran chmod +x /Users/tristan/Documents/Server_Backup/Backup.sh so it should be executable.
Edit:
I added logging to the LaunchDeamon but the log files just stay empty. That would mean that the Deamon isn't even running in the first place. After trying to load and start it I still get the same error as before. This is the code for the logs which I put at the top:
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/daily.0000_out.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/daily.0000_error.log</string>

Edit 2:
I remade the .plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>postgres.backup</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/Backup.sh</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/daily.0000_out.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/daily.0000_error.log</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>18</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>03</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Now the Deamon does run and it creates logs but it still cant run the shell script (I'm guessing because of lack of permissions).
The sell script is:
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="/Users/tristan/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-16"
BACKUP_DIR="/Volumes/Malbec/Backup"

BACKUP_NAME="backup_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
BACKUP_PATH="$BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME"

rsync -a --delete "$SOURCE_DIR/" "$BACKUP_PATH/"

I get this error:
rsync: mkdir "/Volumes/Malbec/Backup/backup_20240430_180305" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/0032d1ee-80fd-11ee-8227-6aecfccc70fe/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(545) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/0032d1ee-80fd-11ee-8227-6aecfccc70fe/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]


What exactly is your question here? If you need help in debugging some of your code, please share the code with us.

Into which LaunchDaemon directory did you put the file? Did you run launchctl with the appropriate options afterwards? Is the script executable (does entering ~/Documents/Server_Backup/Backup.sh execute it)? Is there anything meaningful in the log files?

I put it into /Library/LaunchDaemons. I ran sudo launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.postgres.backup.0000.plist but it says Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error and I ran chmod +x /Users/tristan/Documents/Server_Backup/Backup.sh so It should be executable(I tried executing it manually and it works). I just saw that there is a Error 126 but I can't see what's wrong with the plist.

LaunchDaemons are running as root, does root have access to the full path of the script? Also, the answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366281/launchd-confusion-on-semantics-of-bootstrap-and-bootout-etc-after-reading-manu might help to get the launchctl parameters right.

Also, if launchctl gives an error, this information including the command you run should be in the question. We can‘t see your screen, so without you sharing these things we can‘t know.

I tried the things in the link you send me. Now the Deamons are permanently enabled but still not loaded. I use LaunchControl to view the deamons. I also changed the path to the .sh file to /Users/tristan/ so my home directory as it apparently cant access the files in the documents folder.

We still can‘t see your screen. Please edit the question to add the actual commands run and the output you got (copy/paste from Terminal and format as code).

I got the commands from here:https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/contexts/contexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH212-BEHJDFCA    sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.postgres.backup.daily.0000.plist then sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.postgres.backup.daily.0000.plistand after that sudo launchctl start  /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.postgres.backup.daily.0000.plist

I use Methamphetamine to keep the Mac awake at night. I know that the shell script works because I've run it on its own. It didn't create a backup of the folder so I assume it didn't run.

Ideally, add logging directly to the launchd plist (there are tags for that).

I did add logging now but the logs are just empty.

Honestly, it might be easer to just set up a crontab, or at least use Lingon.

Does this answer your question? Permissions errors when using launchd to run rsync between local drive and afp network drive

I did that but there still is a permission error. If I try it in my home folder though, it works without a problem. The error only apears on the external drive. I cant chown to root. Do you have an idea how rsync can get permissions to that?

When I got this error message: Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
The Deamon was already running. The thing that didn't let it run was this part of the code:
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>

which doesn't let the deamon start when booting the computer (It has to be true).
I have now put the file into the LaunchAgents directory and it works perfectly fine! The only problem is the one with the shell file but that doesn't work because of a different reason. (It works if it creates the folder onto the internal hard drive.)
